# Is regular unsweetened cocoa powder safe uncooked?

Tags: food-safety, cocoa

Presumably, the cocoa isn't raw. I can't find anything on the safety of consuming it uncooked.

I see here the questions on how to make it dissolve in cold milk, but would prefer a stronger confirmation.

Comment: This question never crossed my mind all the years I had used it to make a quick cocoa drink. I am still alive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly safe uncooked, although it may be unpalatable without being sweetened.

For example, you can make your own chocolate milk mix with cocoa powder and powdered sugar.  Simply mix it into milk, without cooking, and enjoy.

It is also dusted uncooked as a garnish or accent on some pastries or cakes.